Grub "failure reading sector" from Live USB
I'm having an issue booting a live USB for Ubuntu 22.04. When selected by my boot manager, I get an error

error: failure reading sector 0x5b88c0 from 'hd0'


This is a 16 GB USB 3.0 drive (type A) and I previously used fdisk to entirely remove the partition table and create a new partition for the whole drive, then format as FAT with the Disks utility in Ubuntu 24.04. I think this would have been a quick format. I then used the Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu to write a 22.04 ISO to the drive, which succeeded, though it couldn't boot in KVM/QEMU.
When I select to boot from the USB drive, I get a boot failure. If I then choose to boot normally and hold Escape, I can enter my computer's grub bootloader, where I then attempt
grub> linux /casper/vmlinuz

I can see this file in grub, and my root appears to be set to the correct drive, but I can't set the kernel, so I can't load the live USB.
I have tried a different USB drive (4 GB USB 2.0) on which I have Ubuntu Sway set up as a live USB, and this works fine, but the 4 GB drive is too small for the Ubuntu 22.04 ISO.
Ultimately, I have had some issues with 24.04 and want to downgrade to 22.04, and with the changes to how apt handles sources, reinstalling from a live USB seems easiest.
I'd like to determine why I can't boot the live USB and how I can correct this so I can install 22.04.
Also, I know there's a similar question about this, but that one appears to be trying to boot from an internal drive and the solution suggests using a live disk, so I'm not sure it's fully applicable.

I decided to try a different USB port on my computer and suddenly the Live USB boots normally...
The other (4 GB) USB is able to boot normally from either of the ports, but for some reason, the larger drive only boots from one of them...
So for others out there struggling with a similar issue, try a different port
For context (since it's now relevant), I am running a Framework 16 with a  Ryzen 7 7840HS with the 7700S dGPU and using USB C to A expansion cards in ports 3 and 6 (the two closest to the front). Port 3 works fine while port 6 shows an issue with the 16 GB drive.
